# Display the quantity of stock in the error message?

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2

I want to display the quantity of stock for my product if the quantity added in the cart is higher than 'in stock'.
Where do I found the error message and edit that ?

Comment: Have you made an effort to find this yourself? You have the error message...so search for it in the magento source code. The forum is here to help, but surely you can do a bit of effort first?

Answer (score 1):

It's sometimes hard to know where to begin in Magento to add functionality. If you just want the answer, skip down to the bottom. This is how I did it:

**Search app/code/core/Mage for part of the text:**

In my case I searched for the words "Out of stock" - and it returned 21 files. So instead I searched for the phrase "Currently out of stock" and it returned only 6 matches in 5 files. One of these had to be it.

In reading through the list of files, one of them was for XmlConnect (for mobile), 3 were for Wishlist. That only left one result that was relevant:

```
app/code/core/Mage/CatalogInventory/Model/Stock/Item.php
```

So I know where the message is now. I need to create a module and a rewrite the method `checkQuoteItemQty`, but - geez - that's a really hairy method; a lot of functionality going on in there... probably don't want to copy and paste the entire method. There's probably a better way...

**Creating the rewrite:**

Create a new module. Create a Model folder and create a folder path like  `app/code/local/YourCompany/YourModule/Model/Stock/Item.php` and tell your new class to extend `Mage_CatalogInventory_Model_Stock_Item`.

You'll create a method there called `checkQuoteItemQty`, and create the model rewrite in your config xml:

```
<models>
    <cataloginventory>
        <rewrite>
            <stock_item>YourCompany_YourModule_Model_Stock_Item</stock_item>
        </rewrite>
    </cataloginventory>
</models>
```

Your model's method will look something like this - and this is the tricky part because you have to test the return error value and then load in the catalog product quantity:

```
public function checkQuoteItemQty($qty, $summaryQty, $origQty = 0)
{
    $result = parent::checkQuoteItemQty($qty, $summaryQty, $origQty);
    if($result->getMessage()==Mage::helper('core')->__('This product is currently out of stock.')){
          $message = Mage::helper('core')->__('Your new message goes in here - items available: %s',$this->getStockQty());
          $result->setMessage($message);
    }
    return $result;
}
```

**Conclusion**

We created a new module, rewrote the parent, *called the parent* from our rewrite, and tested its return value. If the value of the error message matched our desired text, we rewrite it to include the stock amount left.